# Simple form adds padding and shifts some elements on the form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple_form gem

simple_form adds unneeded padding between my inputs, shifts buttons and cuts space between label and input(**check the screenshot**)

How can I fix it?

**explanation of the problem:**
[image]

> **this is the wrapper of the form: edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            Editing: <%= @user.username %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **this is the _form.html.erb**

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user,
   defaults: { input_html: { class: 'form-control ' } },
  html: {class:"form-horizontal form-groups-bordered"} do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <%= f.input :name, placeholder: "", label: false %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact details</label>

        <div class="col-sm-5 ">
            <%= f.input :contact_details,
             placeholder: "",
             label: false %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-ta" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Info</label>

        <div class="col-sm-5" >
          <%= f.input :user_info,
            as: :text,
            placeholder: "",
            input_html: { style:"overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 100px;"},
            label: false %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", @user, class: "btn btn-default" %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a  demo.

Comment: @alirezasafian the screenshot explaines the whole problem

Comment: While the screenshot explaines the problem, we still can not give a solution as the outcome of your code depends on what _simple-form_ actually outputs. Just paste the entire html and css code here and I will be able to help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that *simple_form* adds a wrapper div around inputs (screenshot)

<sup>Not sure, but the last time I used it, it didn't add any wrappers.</sup>

So, I used `f.input_field` instead of `f.input` that according to [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs) removes all the wrapper divs.

Here's one of the updated form inputs.

```
<%= f.input_field :current_build, class:"form-control", label: false %>
```

[image]